# Get the id of a row from a dataframe when it fully matches with a Pandas Series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe and a separate Pandas series (which actually keeps the values of a single row) that matches with one of the rows in that dataframe. I have seen a lot that people find row ids when certain column values match, such as

```
df.index[(df['column_a'] == 10) & (df['column_b'] == 'foo')].tolist()
```

But I need a full match in all of the column values of a row to retrieve the id. I have more than 50 column names so writing all of the columns one by one in a condition would not be feasible. The shape of the dataframe that I want to find the row id is (700,60) and the shape of the Pandas series that I want to find the full match is (60,0), which I could not transpose to (0,60) after extracting it from another dataframe.

So, is there another way to write a condition to get an id of a row from a dataframe when a row's values are identical to the values of a Pandas series?

Comment: kindly post sample dataframe with expected output. Data, not pics

Comment: how can I add a dataframe? @sammywemmy

Comment: you can post the output of ``df.to_dict().head(10)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a boolean mask for the DataFrame with `(df==s).all(axis=1)` (where `df` is the DataFrame and `s` is the Series = one row of the DataFrame):

```
# dataframe
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100),
    'y': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100),
    'z': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100),
})

# series
s = pd.Series({'x': 821, 'y': 863, 'z': 129})

# find the row
df.loc[(df==s).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
      x    y    z
95  821  863  129
```

P.S. And if you just want the index, you can use `idxmax`:

```
(df==s).all(axis=1).idxmax()
```

Output:

```
95
```